# Wait for an Import Operation of Firestore collections to finish

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have the following https callable cloud function that imports all documents found in a backup.

```
    const client = await auth.getClient();

    const path = `${timestamp}`;

    const projectId = await auth.getProjectId();

    // we change the action for importDocuments
    const url = `https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${projectId}/databases/(default):importDocuments`;
    const backup_route = `gs://${BUCKET_NAME}/${path}`;
    return client.request({
        url,
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            inputUriPrefix: backup_route,
        }
    }).then(async (res) => {
        console.log(`Backup restored from folder ${backup_route}`);
        return Promise.resolve(true);
    }).catch(async (e) => {
        return Promise.reject(new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', e.message));
    })
```

The problem is that the promise resolves after successfully beginning the import operation. But it does not wait until the import is finished.

I read the following documentation on the import and long-running operations but didn't find what I was looking for.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases/importDocuments
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/Shared.Types/Operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's the way it works.  API docs for `importDocuments` says it returns an [Operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/Shared.Types/Operation).  According to the docs for Operation:

> This resource represents a long-running operation that is the result of a network API call.

The way I read the APIs in general is that you need to take this Operation object and poll for it periodically using the [methods on operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest#rest-resource:-v1.projects.databases.operations).  It looks like [get](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.operations/get) will do this for you.  You will have to pass it the name of the Operation from its payload that you got from the call to `importDocuments`.  Eventually, it will give you an operation whose `done` property is set to true.

It's very possible that the import will take longer than your function has to run, so the caller of your function will not simply be able to wait until the import is complete.  Client will need to poll another function that keeps checking the operation for completion.

Comment: Thank you, your response was very helpful.

Comment: If you have a moment, it's customary to mark helpful answers as correct using the checkbox to the right, so the person giving the answer can get credit.